# Extracting data from file with differing amounts of columns

Tags: python, unix, awk

I have a tab separated file that appears as so:

```
NM_000014   chr12   -   36  9220303 9220778 9221335 9222340 9223083 9224954 9225248 9227155 9229351 9229941 9230296 9231839 9232234 9232689 9241795 9242497 9242951 9243796 9246060 9247568 9248134 9251202 9251976 9253739 9254042 9256834 9258831 9259086 9260119 9261916 9262462 9262909 9264754 9264972 9265955 9268359     9220435 9220820 9221438 9222409 9223174 9225082 9225467 9227379 9229532 9230016 9230453 9231927 9232411 9232773 9241847 9242619 9243078 9244025 9246175 9247680 9248296 9251352 9252119 9253803 9254270 9256996 9258941 9259201 9260240 9262001 9262631 9262930 9264807 9265132 9266139 9268558     A2M 1
NM_000016   chr1    +   12  76190031    76194085    76198328    76198537    76199212    76200475    76205664    76211490    76215103    76216135    76226806    76228376        76190502    76194173    76198426    76198607    76199313    76200556    76205795    76211599    76215244    76216231    76227055    76229363        ACADM   1
```

As you can tell if you scroll to end of the lines, there are differing amounts of columns corresponding to the numbers listed. What I want to do is output the very last number before the gene name (A2M and ACADM in this case) to a file. Is there any way to do this? I've been trying to figure out a way using unix's `awk`, however I don't believe this will work due to the differing amounts of columns.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(NF-1)` like so where [`NF`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-17) is the number fields for that line:

```
awk  '{print $(NF-1)}' /tmp/genes.txt
A2M
ACADM
```

Your posted example has spaces for delimiters. You may need to change the field separator to tabs if you file is truly tab delimited. Then it would be:

```
awk  -F $'\t' {print $(NF-1)}' file_name
```

If you want the number before that name:

```
$ awk  '{print $(NF-2)}' /tmp/genes.txt
9268558
76229363
```

Comment: I want the last number before the gene. This prints the gene names only.

Comment: Yes, `NF `is the number of fields

Comment: That'll give you the last field, not the second-to-last. But yeah, you can use it.

Comment: To @christy: You need `{print $(NF-2)}` I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' FILE
```

[`NF`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-17) always provides the number of fields, so you can use that in an awk variable to dynamically set the field based on the field length.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your lines structured in the same manner. If so it is pretty straightforward:

```
for line in myLines:
    data = line.split[-3]
```